# How to right align a <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of `<p>` tags that I want to right align.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

CSS:

```
p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

INLINE:

```
<p style="text-align: right">Some Text</p>
```

jQuery:

```
$('p').css('text-align', 'right');
```

Javascript:

```
var aElements = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
for (var i = 0; i < aElements.length; i++) {
    aElements[i].style.textAlign = 'right';
}
```

Comment: Great thanks. I kept seeing vertical-align, but was getting annoyed when I couldn't find horizontal-align.

Answer (score 8):

It depends. Do you want the entire paragraph to align to the right side of whatever container it's in? Or do you want the text of the paragraph to align to the right margin of the paragraph?

If it's the first, look into the float: right; CSS directive. The latter, text-align: right;